# Are the following sets a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I have got stuck in showing whether this particular subsets are submanifolds(smooth):

1. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x)=|x|$. Then the graph of the function f is smooth $1-$dimensional manifold, but it is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

   That it is an $1-$dimensional manifold I have been able to show but I not getting the later part at all.
2. Is the spiral $X$ given as 
             $$X=\{(e^t \cos t,e^t \sin t):\ t \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
   a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I have no idea to show this part as well. I think it would be so. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks for the editing...@Dario.

Comment: Hint: Any submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is locally given by the graph of a smooth function.

Comment: How can I prove this statement?..and how will the conclusion follow then?Could you kindly give me detailed solution to it...@Jose27

Comment: The implicit function theorem. For the first one prove that such a representation would imply that $|x|$ is differentiable at $0$. For the second prove that there is no graph (not even continuous) representing $X$ at $0$.

Comment: Kindly explain why in the second part we cant have a graph(even a continuous one!!).....@Jose27

Comment: Take a line through the origin, then any line perpendicular to this will intersect $X$ in more than one point.

Comment: thanks...and what can we say about submanifolds in higher euclidean spaces..they are still graph of a smooth function locally by implicit function theorem??..like how can we say that open mobius strip is submanifold of R^3?....@Jose27